# PHP SoapServer ampersand is encoded

Tags: php, soap, soapserver

I'm working on a webservice using SoapServer in PHP. Previously, I made another webservice using exactly the same technique. My new project is on the same server, but in another subdirectory. 
In the url of the service and the soapserver is a version number included. 
This is the way my SoapServer is created in PHP:

```
$server = new SoapServer("https://".DOMAIN."/webservice/index.php?v=1.0.0&wsdl=1");
$server->setClass('SoapHandler');
$server->handle();
```

The whole PHP page is the same in my example Soap Service, only the url is different ofcourse.
When I do a call to the webservice with soapUI, the following error is returned:

```
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://myurl.com/webservice/index.php?v=1.0.0&amp;wsdl=1' : failed to load external entity "https://myurl.com/webservice/index.php?v=1.0.0&amp;wsdl=1"
```

As you can see, the ampersand is replaced with `&amp;`. I tried to change the encoding to UTF-8, this doesn't work either.

Who can help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had an .htaccess, only allowing my IP address while it should also allow the server's IP.. Deleting this solved the problem. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You have to enable your openssl module in your `php.ini` file. Otherwise you can't access a domain with SSL (https).

Otherwise you should check your domain from your local server and check the return of the WSDL file with curl or lynx.

Comment: The other webservice is on the same domain (and thus webserver), and that one does actually work.. So I guess my webserver settings are fine?

Comment: You can check it with a phpinfo. SSL in Apache is a different thing as php openssl sorry i have updated my Answer. You have to enable your openssl in your php.ini file.

Comment: SSL is enabled, I checked it with a phpinfo. But the SSL is set up for the whole server in de php.ini, and the other Soap service on the same server does work..

Comment: I had a same problem yesterday. You should check wheather you get the correct WSDL file when you access your WSDL url from your local server.

Comment: The WSDL seems to be correct, since I can see the WSDL file if I view in my browser. The validator in Visual Studio also shows no errors..